# Open form action in another html page iframe

Tags: html, forms, iframe

I'm trying to open a form action url in a iframe which is in another html page.
I successfully opened it in a iframe which is on the same page with this code:

```
<form class="form" action="myConnexionURL" target="iframe-myAccount" method="post">
     <input type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="ID">
     <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="PSW">
     <input type="submit" value="Connexion">
</form>

<iframe src="" name="iframe-myAccount"></frame>
```

So, my question is simple: How can I open the `form` action url in an iframe which is in another `html` page?

Comment: You want to get the URL for the form's `action` attribute and then display it in an iframe? *Just* the URL? Nothing to do with the request?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to access that iFrame directly.  I think you'll have to pass the data to the parent and then have it adjust the URL for the embedded iFrame.  I'd probably do this through server-side scripting, but you may be able to do it through JavaScript.